# missing project properties in VS2019 setup project

Tags: visual-studio, installation, properties

I am trying to create an installer for a project by adding a "Setup Project" to my solution, but it seems that some of the usual properties are missing (e.g. UpgradeCode and Version) -- see screenshot, and no, I didn't just forget how to scroll down. I'm using VS2019 Community. How can I recover these properties?

[missing properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlIJW.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it seems there are more lines of property items, but may be covered by the other window. Perhaps you can kindly try to re-dock the Setup Project’s property window and check again.

[image]

I also noticed that you mentioned “I didn’t just forget how to scroll down”, so I also consider if this issue is caused by the specific project type or may be affected by the version of the Setup Project extension.

I suggest you update and use the latest version of the “Setup Project” extension, and try to uninstall and reinstall it, if necessary. And, perhaps you can share me your project type and it will be better to test/reproduce on my side.

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed covered by another window. I don't know why I failed to notice it.

Comment: @user16599420, you are welcome, if your issue has been solved, please do not forget to [accept the useful answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and if your issue persists, feel free to let me know.